# Knockout subscribe triggers on page load for selectbox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created an extender using subscribe with the purpose of intercept a user change of an input field and forcing a value to be set.

For example, I have set a forced value of "Bar" on an observable. If the user changes it to "Foo" I will force it to "Bar" and notify the user.
(it's for a prototype/example solution).

It works for text boxes and radio buttons **but not for selectboxes**. It seems to be triggered on page load, not only on change.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4gus57pd/7/

```
ko.extenders.forcedValue = function(target, newValue) {
    target.subscribe(function(writtenValue) {
        console.log(target()+" - "+newValue);
        if(newValue != writtenValue){
            alert("In this example we will use the value "+newValue+" instead.");
        }           
        target(newValue);
    });     
    return target;
};
this.textbox = ko.observable("Foo").extend({ forcedValue: "Bar" });
this.selectbox = ko.observable(1).extend({ forcedValue: 2 });
```

When you run it the select box extender is triggered despite the value hasn't been changed?

Comment: It changes for me just fine in the fiddle. (FF 51.0.1, Chrome 55.0.2883, IE 11), however, on pageload, the value is 1 in all of the browsers despite the alert popping up.

Comment: @Balázs Thats the problem, that the alert is triggered on page load. Should only popup when changing to a different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute is a `string`, so knockout will try to match the values `["1", "2", "3"]` to your observable, which holds either the number `1` or `2`. It doesn't see a selected value, so it updates your observable to the first `<option>`.

For a quick solution, change your `selectbox` to `ko.observable("1")` and the forced value to `"2"`.

**Additional advice, not related to the problem:**

Your current extender will always trigger two subscription changes. One for the first change, and one for the actual reset. If you wrap the observable in a read/write computed, you counter this:

```
ko.extenders.forcedValue = function(target, forcedValue) {
  return ko.computed({
    read: target.extend({ notify: "always" }),
    write: function(newValue) {
      console.log("Attempt:", target(), "->", newValue);

      if (newValue !== forcedValue) {
        console.log("Using " + forcedValue + " instead."); 
        target(forcedValue);
      } else {
        target(newValue);
      }

    }
  }).extend({ notify: "always" });
};
```

Comment: Of course! Thats why it worked when I used an observable array for the options instead. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice, never really understood how to use the read/write options. Appreciate it!

Comment: Your script only seems to work for the first change, if you change the value several times it slips through? jsfiddle.net/4gus57pd/14
Or, it seems to keep the value if you reload the page but upon change it looks like it doesn't..

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten an additional `notify: "always"` extender. What happens is that when the computed "skips" an invalid update, the value goes from `2` to `2`. This does not trigger an update automatically, so the UI will start lagging behind. The `read` observable needs to be told to *always* share an attempt at setting a new value. Fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/8gpyjLj2/

Comment: Appreciate the fix and explanation!